# Using trigger to generate ID vs creating IDs manually

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

If we have a sequence to generate unique ID fields for a table, which of the 2 approaches is more efficient:

1. Create a trigger on insert, to populate the ID field by fetching nextval from sequence.
2. Calling nextval on the sequence in the application layer before inserting the object (or tuple) in the db.

EDIT: The application performs a mass upload. So assume thousands or a few millions of rows to be inserted each time the app runs. Would triggers from #1 be more efficient than calling the sequence within the app as mentioned in #2?

Comment: I can't imagine an app that consumes data with no ID.

Comment: For e.g., if you have a table for tags-post relation.. All the app would do is query either by the tag name or by post id. It would never query the table by the id generated for the relation table. But it would still be a nice idea to keep the Id column. Plus, that is not even the point of the question.

Comment: Since you're on MySQL why don't you use an `auto increment`? Otherwise I think you should use solution one, since the whole stuff will stay on the db side, avoiding that specific stuff in the application layer

Comment: I'm not on MySql. I'm on Oracle. I tagged both DBs just because they are popular. I think the solution should be the same irrespective of the DB provider.

Comment: As soon as you're concerned about *efficiency*, you should expect to get different answers for each database - possibly different answers for each database *version*.

Comment: I would love to learn more about how each database differs in this case.

Comment: Well, MySQL does not have sequences as first-class objects among other major architectural differences-- you wouldn't create a sequence object, you wouldn't call `nextval` on the sequence, you wouldn't create a trigger.  You would declare the column in the table `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  It's a completely different architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are inserting a large number of rows, the most efficient approach would be to include the `sequence.nextval` as part of the SQL statement itself, i.e.

```
INSERT INTO table_name( table_id, <<other columns>> )
  VALUES( sequence_name.nextval, <<bind variables>> )
```

or

```
INSERT INTO table_name( table_id, <<other columns>> )
  SELECT sequence_name.nextval, <<other values>>
    FROM some_other_table
```

If you use a trigger, you will force a context shift from the SQL engine to the PL/SQL engine (and back again) for every row you insert.  If you get the nextval separately, you'll force an additional round-trip to the database server for every row.  Neither of these are particularly costly if you do them once or twice.  If you do them millions of times, though, the milliseconds add up to real time.

Answer (score 2):

If you're only concerned about performance, on Oracle it'll generally be a bit faster to populate the ID with a sequence in your INSERT statement, rather than use a trigger, as triggers add a bit of overhead.

However (as Justin Cave says), the performance difference will probably be insignificant unless you're inserting millions of rows at a time. Test it to see.

Answer (score 0):

What is a key? One or more fields to uniquely identify records, should be final and never change in the course of an application.

I make a difference between technical and business keys. Technical keys are defined on the database and are generated (sequence, uuid, etc ); business keys are defined by your domain model.

That's why I suggest

- always generate technical PK's with a sequence/trigger on the database
- never use this PK field in your application ( tip: mark the getId()
  setId() @Deprecated )
- define business fields which uniquely identify your entity and use these in equals/hashcode methods

Answer (score 0):

I'd say if you already use hibernate, then let it control how the id's are created with `@SequenceGenerator` and `@GeneratedValue`. It will be more transparent, and Hibernate can reserve id's for itself so it might be more efficient than doing it by hand, or from a trigger.